# How to get this JButton to work?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

I am having some serious trouble on JButtons. My problem is that the JButton just won't show up, no matter what I try. I've been trying everything for over an hour, and nothing has worked, so I think it is time to ask here. Here is my code. It's just the constructor because the whole class is really big and you don't need to see it.

```
public Game() {

    frame = new JFrame(NAME);
    canvas = new Canvas();

    canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
    canvas.setFocusable(false);

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.setSize(width, height);

    frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setFocusable(true);
    frame.requestFocus();

    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JButton play = new JButton("Hi");

    panel.add(play);
    frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

}
```

Comment: try `frame.add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);`

Comment: You have to give the `JPanel` a layout. Either `BorderLayout`, `BoxLayout`, ... Take a look here [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: @NicoT *"You have to give the `JPanel` a layout."* By default, panels have a `FlowLayout` so ..no you don't.

Comment: BTW - please give your class a more unique name than `Game` even if it takes adding your own name like `ElijahEeedaritaGame`. Do you realise just how many broken `Game` classes I've dealt with in my time? My IDE is baulking at deleting all parts of the previous broken `Game` ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problems:

1. `frame.pack();` should be done after all components are added.
2. `frame.setVisible(true);` is best put after all adding, packing & configuration.

---

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Game {

    private JFrame frame = null;
    private Canvas canvas = null;
    private String NAME = "Moronically Named Game";
    int width = 500;
    int height = 200;

    public Game() {

        frame = new JFrame(NAME);
        canvas = new Canvas();

        canvas.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));
        canvas.setFocusable(false);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.setSize(width, height);

        frame.add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setFocusable(true);
        frame.requestFocus();

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JButton play = new JButton("Hi");

        panel.add(play);
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
        panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width, height));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (Exception useDefault) {
                }
                Game o = new Game();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}
```

### Other tips:

1. For better help sooner, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). E.G. as seen in my answer. You posted an uncompilable code snippet in the question, I turned it into an MCVE for the answer.
2. See [Should I avoid the use of set(Preferred|Maximum|Minimum)Size methods in Java Swing?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7229226/418556)  (Yes.)
3. As to layout out the GUI with padding as mentioned in tip (2). Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height.

Comment: N.B. After looking more closely at your code, I realised this will not produce what you expect either. I'll give the problem a further look once you've done tips 1 & 3. The ball is in your court..

Comment: This actually worked. However, in the end I decided to add my own GUI system to fit better with the program. I still put in the frame.pack() and frame.setVisible(true) at the end. Also, one more question, is it okay to use setPreferredSize on a canvas, since it doesn't need to change dimensions?

Comment: The advice in that linked thread is to override the `getPreferredSize()` method, rather than call `setPReferredSize()` ..

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you have provided I believe the `canvas = new Canvas()` component covered the entire JFrame since you have set it's dimension same with the jframe which makes the other component looks like not showing.

- I suggest that you should be more careful on combining swing(lightweight) and awt(heavyweight) components see this one [Mixing heavyweight and lightweight components](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/mixing-components-433992.html)